# Activate or deactivate features in Karaf

Tags: apache-karaf

Is there any proper way to activate/deactivate a feature in `karaf` in a custom distribution, for example changing a configuration file or so

Currently I have a solution using a configuration file and a bundle activator to check if the flag is true or false, if it is true then the bundle activator take care of turn on or turn off the feature and their bundles associated.

is good the approach or exists something better?

I am expecting a cleaner way to achieve the same behavior.

Note: I know exists SRC components but this approach is pretty much similar to my current approach in my opinion.